# Playstation Eye Cam model: sleh-00448

Tags: audio, drivers, webcam, microphone

I managed to download and install a driver for this camera *Playstation Eye Cam  model: sleh-00448" from https://archive.org/download/CLEyeDriver5.3.0.0341Emuline/CL-Eye-Driver-5.3.0.0341-Emuline.exe
The camera is working fine but I cannot get the microphone to work.
I have tried looking for it under audio/sounds from the control panel but it does not show up. Nor can I see it in the settings or options on programs eg Zoom
Please help!

Comment: There are some [presumed](https://web.archive.org/web/20141004085056/http://forum.free-track.net/index.php?showtopic=2416&page=3) registry edits you could try, and some alleged [problems](https://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/497/#2591) with power cycling after sleep or reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes You need a USB socket with higher current supply. That was my problem with connecting camera to the HP monitor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180448)